# Expo XDE cannot run application throws Tunnel packager not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, exponentjs, expo

Has anyone encountered this error:

`Tunnel packager.yu-tyd.my-app.exp.direct not found`

My app is just simple hello world

```
import Expo from 'expo'
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

const App = () => (
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
)

Expo.registerRootComponent(App)
```

Not sure what is causing the error. Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/ex-navigation": "^2.9.2",
    "expo": "^15.0.2",
    "react": "~15.4.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/exponent/react-native/archive/sdk-15.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: I just found this problem, try to close project then open again. It work for me.

Comment: i found the best workarounds for the issue [here](https://exhesham.com/2017/12/06/overcoming-expo-xde-issues/)

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same error; In my case, my internet connection was not reliable and it could not reach the local URL of the running code, since it cannot Tunnel there (Tunneling in Expo makes sure we are able running code behind a VPN.

A recommendation from Expo team:

*Note: If you are on MacOS and XDE gets stuck on “Waiting for packager and tunnel to start”, you may need to install watchman on your machine. The easiest way to do this is with Homebrew, brew install watchman.*